# Increment / Decrement quantity number on WooCommerce using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, woocommerce

I'm using the following to add + and - buttons to my WooCommerce store. It's working, except once clicked it will change every item quantity in the cart instead of just the specific product. I can't seem to solve it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="quantity">
<label for="quantity5432">Quantity</label>
<input type="number" id="quantity5432" class="qty" step="1" min="0" name="cart[73d][qty]" value="0">
</div>

<div class="quantity-nav">
<div class="quantity-button add-action add-up">+</div>
<div class="quantity-button add-action add-down">-</div>
</div>
```

And here's the jQuery

````
$(document).ready(function() {
  const minus = $('.add-down');
  const plus = $('.add-up');
  const input = $('.qty');
  minus.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = input.val();
    if (value > 1) {
      value--;
    }
    input.val(value);
  });

  plus.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = input.val();
    value++;
    input.val(value);
  })
});```
````

Comment: select by id instead of class. Probably all of  your quantity inputs have class `.qty`

Comment: @EvikGhazarian How would an ID help? They would have the same ID or if they had a different ID each, how would I implement it in jQuery to only execute that specific ID once clicked?

Comment: "quantity5432" Does this id follows any pattern? If not. You can add data attributes to the input. Like `data-name`.

Comment: They cannot have the same id. Ids must be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust your script to target the specific input with the class `.qty` by selecting this input in the minus and add `click()` events based on the location of the click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const minus = $('.add-down');
  const plus = $('.add-up');
  minus.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = $(this).closest(".quantity-nav").prev(".quantity").find(".qty");
    var value = input.val();
    if (value > 1) {
      value--;
    }
    input.val(value);
  });

  plus.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = $(this).closest(".quantity-nav").prev(".quantity").find(".qty");
    var value = input.val();
    value++;
    input.val(value);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <label for="quantity5432">Quantity</label>
  <input type="number" id="quantity5432" class="qty" step="1" min="0" name="cart[73d][qty]" value="0">
</div>
<div class="quantity-nav">
  <div class="quantity-button add-action add-up">+</div>
  <div class="quantity-button add-action add-down">-</div>
</div>
<div class="quantity">
  <label for="quantity5433">Quantity</label>
  <input type="number" id="quantity5433" class="qty" step="1" min="0" name="cart[73e][qty]" value="0">
</div>

<div class="quantity-nav">
  <div class="quantity-button add-action add-up">+</div>
  <div class="quantity-button add-action add-down">-</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. May God bless you.

Comment: @JohnSmith Thanks, glad that I was able to help.